# amature bone issue

Tags: modeling, armature, bones, constraints

Blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/71bce00a56eb4703afa318be6672f20e

Here is the tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07e1NUjYY_8&t=243s&ab_channel=BlenderFun

I am following a tutorial, and I've done everything as the video, except that once I get to 4:05 into the video I can't assign the armature as the target like the video does. I'm using version 3.1 and IDK why it's not working. When I tell the one bone to target the armature in the constraint tab, it won't select the armature no matter how many times I click it from the dropdown menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've chosen the wrong tab, don't assign an *Object Constraint* (which will affect the whole armature), instead assign a *Bone Constraint* (which will affect the selected bone only):

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks again moonboots, you are great help. I didn't know there were a separate constraints tab just for bones, so when the person said constraints tab, I went to the one I have always seen and used before. Thank you, gain so much.